# Maharal on Bava Basra 25A

Tags: talmud-gemara, bava-batra, maharal

I saw in the Artscroll Talmud, Tractate Bava Basra, at the very end of 25A:

The Gemara quotes a Baraisa concerning the path of the sun: A Baraisa has taught: R' Eliezer says: The world resembles a pavilion, in that it is enclosed on three sides and open on the fourth; - and the northern side is not enclosed......

> [Maharal (Chidushei Aggados) maintains that the Gemara here is not discussing the actual astronomical phenomena, but a metaphysical concept couched in astronomical language; see there for his detailed explanation (see also his Be'er HaGolah, Be'er 6).]

........This brings us back to R' Eliezer.  The Baraisa resumes.  What is the meaning of the verse which states: From the inner chamber comes the whirlwind - this refers to the south wind, which comes from the innermost region of the world; and from the dispersed parts, the cold - this refers to the north wind, which comes from the open side of the world.  The Baraisa continues with an exposition of the next verse.  By the Breathe of G-d He gives ice - this refers to the west wind; and an expanse of water in a torrent - this refers to the east wind.

If anyone could possibly provide the Maharal's detailed explanation of this Gemara in Chidushei Aggados and in Be'er Hagolah, Be'er 6, in English, I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: His explanation is rather complicated. There's an artscroll book on Beer HaGolah I bet it's explained properly there.

Comment: You have to understand the Maharal's concept of North, South, East and West, first. (The Maharal understands that these are fundamental aspects of the *briah* and not just directions.)